# query the partner of duplicates from the unique subset data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df), which have many duplicates but with unique rownames.

```
df = read.table(text="ID    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9
Chr01A_7164 A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   H
Chr01A_7230 A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   H
Chr01A_7444 A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   H
Chr01A_14994    A   A   H   A   A   A   A   A   A
Chr01A_59238    A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
Chr01A_61882    A   H   A   A   A   H   A   A   A
Chr01A_66693    A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
Chr01A_66741    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A
Chr01A_66776    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A
Chr01A_67014    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A
Chr01A_67096    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
df <- data.frame(df, row.names = 1)
```

df1 is the unique set data frame from df, and df2 is the duplicates in df.

```
df1 <- df[!duplicated(df),]
df1
             S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9
Chr01A_7164   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  H
Chr01A_14994  A  A  H  A  A  A  A  A  A
Chr01A_59238  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A
Chr01A_61882  A  H  A  A  A  H  A  A  A
Chr01A_66741  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A

df2 <- df[duplicated(df),]
df2
            S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9
Chr01A_7230   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  H
Chr01A_7444   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  H
Chr01A_66693  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A
Chr01A_66776  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A
Chr01A_67014  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A
Chr01A_67096  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A
```

I want to a column in df2 to query the corresponding partner of the duplicate from the unique set df1. The result is expected as:

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  duplicated_df1
Chr01A_7230 A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   H   Chr01A_7164
Chr01A_7444 A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   H   Chr01A_7164
Chr01A_66693    A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   Chr01A_59238
Chr01A_66776    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A   Chr01A_66741
Chr01A_67014    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A   Chr01A_66741
Chr01A_67096    A   A   A   A   B   A   A   A   A   Chr01A_66741
```

is there any simple way to do this in r? Thanks for any helps!

Comment: As a future note, its not advised to verbatim repost [your closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77369578/how-to-track-removed-duplicates-in-data-frame-in-r) - this clutters up the site and you may get some negative attention. If the answer didnt work, you could have commented and pinged (@) the folks asking you for reproducibility (me :) so they they would know you updated it. Glad you found an answer!

Comment: @jpsmith I remember your comments. I didn't know who I need to contact to look over the updated question. Now I know who I need talk with in the future.

Comment: @user2344212 no worries, just trying to make sure you were away and avoid any potential blowback next time. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could do

```r
df2$duplicated_df1 <- rownames(df1)[
  match(apply(df2, 1, paste, collapse = ' '), 
        apply(df1, 1, paste, collapse = ' '))]
```

Which gives you

```r
df2
#>              S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 duplicated_df1
#> Chr01A_7230   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  H    Chr01A_7164
#> Chr01A_7444   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  H    Chr01A_7164
#> Chr01A_66693  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A   Chr01A_59238
#> Chr01A_66776  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A   Chr01A_66741
#> Chr01A_67014  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A   Chr01A_66741
#> Chr01A_67096  A  A  A  A  B  A  A  A  A   Chr01A_66741
```

Comment: instead of `apply` you should consider using `do.call` ie `match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1))`